# Is there a standard name for this property of ordered pairs of binary operations?

Tags: terminology, binary-operations

I know that the distributive property of ordered pairs of binary operations is well-known. However, I have thought of a new property of ordered pairs of binary operations. Let $+$ and $*$ be the binary operations on a set $S$, which are arbitrary. (So, for example, don't confuse $+$ with addition). I define $(+,*)$ to be switchable iff for all $x,y,z$ in $S$, $(x+(y*z))=((x+y)*z)$. So, for example, $(+,-)$, where $+$ represents addition on the reals and $-$ represents binary subtraction on the reals, is a switchable pair of binary operations. Also, an operation $*$ is associative iff the pair $(*,*)$ is switchable. Is there a standard name for this property? Also, has any book or paper defined this property?

Comment: Just a quick observation: suppose $f$ is **any** unary function and $\star_1,\star_2$ are binary operations such that $\star_1$ is associative and $a\star_2b=a\star_1(f(b))$. For example, take $\star_1$ to be addition, $\star_2$ to be multiplication, and $f(x)=-x$. Then we have $$a\star_1(b\star_2 c)=a\star_1(b\star_1(f(c)))=(a\star_1b)\star_1(f(c))=(a\star_1b)\star_2c.$$ So since subtraction is just addition with the second coordinate modified by a unary function, we get the relevant property.

Comment: Do you intend order to matter? That is, (x+(y$*$z))=((x+y)$*$z) would be called the switchable law for the ordered operation pair (+,$*$) whereas exchanging + and $*$ in that would give the switchable law for the ordered operation pair ($*$,+). So that would be (x$*$(y+z))=((x$*$y)+z) which is different.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I intend order to matter.

Comment: Derp, in my comment "multiplication" should of course be "subtraction."

Answer (score 1):

This is an equation in the [term algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra) of signature $\{+, *\}$, but I don't think this specific equation has an accepted name.